# Looking for a tool (possibly on Linux) that will allow me to make a manual HTTP or HTTPS request

Tags: linux, http, https

I am looking for a tool (possibly on Linux) that will allow me to make a manual HTTP or HTTPS request. By manual, I really mean it: I should be able to feed it a text file which looks like

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11

Hello world
```

and a destination URL (`www.example.com/foo`), and send the request to the URL. At most, it would be useful if the `Content_Length` header was automatically computed.

I would be able to write such a tool using some library like httplib in Python, but the very reason I need it is to do manual investigation when something goes wrong with such libraries.

Comment: https specific question: https://superuser.com/questions/346958/can-the-telnet-or-netcat-clients-communicate-over-ssl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) has a --post-file option which should work for you.

Edit: Also, there's [Ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-ssl.html), which you would use in a similar fashion to Randolf Richardson's telnet suggestion, except that it also supports SSL/HTTPS:

```
ncat -C --ssl www.example.com 443 < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: If you need HTTPS, use openssl instead of netcat: openssl s_client -connect <address>:443

Comment: wget --post-file will add headers and use the specified file only for the body of the request.

Answer (score 6):

For HTTP (not HTTPS), one alternative to the "wget" command that comes to mind is to use telnet as follows:

- telnet hostname 80 < input.txt > output.txt

The file "input.txt" is your list of pre-set commands that you wish to feed to the host at *hostname* and the file "output.txt" will store the response.

Comment: This made me wonder if netcat supports SSL, and lo-and-behold, there's Ncat, an SSL-enabled netcat clone.

Comment: @Chris Acheson (+1):  That's fantastic!  Please feel free to copy what I wrote in a separate answer and adapt it to a solution that utilizes NetCat (I'll vote for your answer if you do this).

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a GET request with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect cdn.sstatic.net:443 <<eof
GET /stackexchange/js/universal-login.js HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: cdn.sstatic.net

eof
```

Note that you can also use "HTTP/2", but be careful because some servers
(e.g. github.com) do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked creating a request file (Example: `request.txt`)

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
Connection: close

Hello world
```

And then call the `openssl s_client` command:

`cat request.txt | openssl s_client -quiet -connect www.example.com:443`

However, be careful about some points:

- The file must be **encoded** properly, specially the content body. Better if you include a header `Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` if the file is utf-8 encoded.
- The **line endings** for the headers must be **CR/LF**. Only with LF the web server could return `HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`, because the standard HTTP protocol uses CR/LF for line endings (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html). You can use the `unix2dos` command to do this conversion.
- Add a `Connection: close` header to terminate the request and return from the call. Otherwise, the command will be awaiting for user interaction, if the server normally responds with a `Connection: keep-alive` header.

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised no one mentioned [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). It is made **exactly** for what you want to do. And it is available on practically any platform (including Windows).

So for your example all you would do is:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d 'Hello World' www.example.com
```

Which captured from Wireshark will net you:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11

Hello world
```

You can easily modify the headers further if you wish to do all kinds of stuff (i.e. change the user-agent, etc).

Edit: Didn't notice the "from a file" requirement. You can do that too, either plain ascii or binary files. You just specify the filename with an @ symbol

```
-d @/tmp/HelloWorldFile
```

Comment: curl is **almost** what I want, but requires me to specify the headers on the command line, which is very impractical. I need something which allows me to specify the **complete** text of the request, including the method and the headers, from a file, and ncat does eaxctly what I want. Thank you anyway :-)