# Can the telnet or netcat clients communicate over SSL?

Tags: connection, ssl, telnet, netcat, tls

I would like to test client connections with IMAP over SSL, HTTPS, and other secure text-based Internet protocols over SSL/TLS, the same way I would using telnet or netcat if they were not tunneled over a secure protocol.  Is there a way to get telnet or netcat to go through SSL/TLS such as with a pipe or alternate program?

Comment: Same on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/102032/connecting-to-https-with-netcat-nc

Answer (score 169):

There is no Telnet/Netcat client – they are two separate programs, and there exist *at least* 10 different Telnet clients and at least 6 different Netcat versions *(original netcat, GNU netcat, OpenBSD netcat, nmap's ncat; forgot the rest).*

The preferred tools come from TLS libraries themselves. They might be a bit verbose, though.

- **GnuTLS**  has a TLS client tool on Linux:

  ```
  gnutls-cli imap.gmail.com -p 993
  ```

  Use `-s` for STARTTLS; you will need to manually enter the necessary protocol commands and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> when ready.

  Supports IPv6, validates server certificates by default.
- **OpenSSL** has a TLS client tool:

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993
  ```

  This is available for all operating systems. STARTTLS is supported via `-starttls imap` or `-starttls smtp` options, and the program will automatically negotiate it. (Although it throws away the initial server reply after doing so, but it's usually fine.)

  Only version ≥ 1.1 supports IPv6.

  Only version ≥ 1.0.2 (IIRC) validates server certificate by default; older versions require manual -CApath specification.

(I'd like to also have tools for testing NSS and SChannel, but couldn't find any.)

The programs also use the same libraries, but might have fewer configuration knobs. Some even skip on peer certificate checks by default...

- **socat**:

  ```
  socat openssl:imap.gmail.com:993 stdio
  ```

  *readline* mode can be used for convenience:

  ```
  socat ssl:imap.gmail.com:993 readline
  ```

  STARTTLS is not supported.
- **ncat** from nmap supports TLS (but not STARTTLS):

  ```
  ncat --ssl imap.gmail.com 993
  ```
- *Some* Telnet clients, such as the **telnet-ssl** package on Debian, also support TLS:

  ```
  telnet-ssl -z ssl imap.gmail.com 993
  ```

  STARTTLS can be activated using `starttls` from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> escape menu.

Comment: I wish I could simply favorite your answer instead of the question that the asker didn't even bother marking as accepted.

Comment: gnutls-cli also seems to be the only one, with which I can test STARTLS with IPv6. Thanks!

Comment: OpenSSL `s_client` has IPv6 support in the 1.1 release.

Comment: @grawity I would really appreciate if you can check this similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/887224/ssl-unsupported-protocol-error

Comment: OpenSSL's `s_client` has a "useful" feature where lines that begin with R or Q are treated as commands (see [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/s_client.html#CONNECTED-COMMANDS)). Use `-ign_eof` to disable this. Also, `s_client` will continue even if verification fails; you have to check that it says "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" and hope the server doesn't try to spoof this message. Better to use `gnutls-cli` if possible.

Comment: Luckily it also has `-verify_return_error` for that.

Comment: The `-verify_return_error` option indeed works, provided `-verify` is also specified (this tripped me up when I wrote my previous comment).

Answer (score 10):

You may want to look at `openssl s_client`:

```
openssl s_client -connect dummy.com:8443
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called `stunnel`, that turns a client or server that doesn't support SSL into one that does, working for client-side, server-side, or both, and you tell it what port to listen on and forward to.

Note- This is ok-ish, though I had worded this a bit differently. You can look at prior edits to see what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you need cross-platform support, there's [`sclient`](https://telebit.cloud/sclient/) ([Git](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/sclient.go)):

- Create a local server that unwraps TLS for `example.com`:

  ```
  sclient example.com:443 localhost:3000
    [listening] example.com:443 <= localhost:3000
  ```
- Make a request to `example.com` via `telnet`:

  ```
  telnet localhost 3000
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com
    Connection: close
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, there is (or was?) a thing called [TelnetS](https://www.micropolis.com/support/kb/micropolis-bbs-faq#Is_there_a_secure_Telnet), a "secured Telnet via TLS/SSL". Debian still provides the telnetd server component in package *telnet-ssl*. Per the linked resource it seems there should be a telnet client in existence, that has a "-z switch" to make the telnet command speak SSL - but I couldn't find this binary. This binary though, would fit as your requested debug helper tool.